# Relation between the number of spanning trees and the chromatic number of a graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, spanning-tree

The number of spanning trees $\tau(G)$ of a simple graph $G$ is seen to satisfy the deletion-contraction recurrence:
$$\tau(G)=\tau(G-e)+\tau(G.e),$$ 
where $e$ is an edge of the graph $G$ and $G-e$ denotes the graph $G$ with edge $e$ deleted and $G.e$ denotes the graph $G$ with the edge $e$ contracted.

Now, the chromatic polynomial $P(G)$ also satisfies a similar deletion-contraction relation:
$$P(G)=P(G-e)-P(G.e).$$
This gives rise to the question that is there some sort of a relation between the chromatic properties and the number of spanning trees in a graph $G$. Specifically,

> 1. Is there a relation between the number of spanning trees and the chromatic number of a graph?
> 2. Are they at least asymptotically related?

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Well there's the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial

Comment: @SamHopkins thanks, but can we have a relation between the chromatic number and the number of spanning trees as such?

Comment: No, for example the bipartite graph K_{n,n} has many spanning trees, whereas a 2n vertex graph obtained from a clique on k-1 vertices plus 2n-k isolated vertices, then add a vertex adjacent to all others, has only k^{k-2} spanning trees. Sam Hopkins’ answer is really correct, for note what deletion-contraction is not really finding optimal colourings, it’s counting not necessarily optimal colourings.